# Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

hello everyone i am getting a problem while updating my record..when i click the edit button it doesnot update the record but give following errors to all post variables.. i would really appreciate any kind of comments or help...

this is     courses-edit.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php

if ($_SESSION["isteacher"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$courseid=$_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (id='".$courseid."')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $id=$row['id'];
   $title = $row['title'];
   $des = $row['description'];
   $subjectid = $row['subjects-id'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $("form").validity(function() {
                $("#title")
                    .require("This Field Must Be Filled!!")
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php include("../includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/nav.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent">
<div class="span-24 last">
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a> >
     <a href="manage-courses.php">Manage Courses</a> >
     <a href="courses-list.php">List Courses</a> >
     Edit Course
</div>
</div>
<?php include("../teacher/includes/manage-courses-aside.php"); ?>
<div class="span-18 last">
<h2 class="alt">Edit Course</h2>

<form id="form" method="post" action="courses-edit-action.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>" name="id" />
 <label>Course Name:</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="text"   value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Choose Subject:</label>
<?php

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjects");

echo "<select name='subjects-id'>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['id'] . "'";
if ($subjectid==$row['id'])
echo 'selected="selected"';
echo " >" . $row['subjectname'] . "</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
mysql_close($con);
?>
<label>Description:</label><textarea name="description" id="description"><?php echo    $des; ?></textarea><br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Course" class="button" />
</form>

<?php include("../includes/footer.php"); ?>
<?php
}
else
{
    header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");

}
?>
```

and this is     courses-edit-action.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php

$id=$_POST["id"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
$des=$_POST["description"];
$subjectid=$_POST["subjects-id"];

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("ombts", $con);
$query=("UPDATE courses SET title='".$title."', description='".$des."', 'subjects-  id'='".$subjectid."' WHERE (id='".$id."')");
$query=mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
echo header("Location:manage-courses.php?status=2");
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and the warnings are

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\courses-edit-action.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\courses-edit-action.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\courses-edit-action.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: subjects-id in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\courses-edit-action.php on line 7
```

Comment: Are you able to get any result if you add the following line into courses-edit-action.php `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: This line `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>" name="id" />` the  quotes are wrong

Comment: also, use mysql_real_escape_string to stop the SQL injection

Comment: You're variables arent being passed along from the form. try `print_r($_POST);` as suggested above. to see what you're getting.

Comment: Please show us the HTML-output of the form.

Comment: @Steven  i've tried it its just saying Array()

Comment: @shakabra whts the right way then? please tell me where are the wrong quotes? thanx :)

Comment: @Riu2009 Then your `POST` does not have any content. To be entirely sure, do a `print_r($_REQUEST)`. If it's still blank, then no data is sent from previous page. Personally I've started to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `POST` and `GET`. It prevents me from doing mistakes of trying to get POST data when I'm sending GET data.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your script like this....

```
    $id= isset($_POST["id"]) ?$_POST["id"] : 0 ;
    $title= isset($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : '' ;
    $des=isset($_POST["description"]) ? $_POST["description"] : '';
    $subjectid= isset($_POST["subjects-id"]) ? $_POST["subjects-id"] : '';
```

Edited
Also, i see an error here...

```
$query=mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
```

should be

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
```

If you still can't update the table, print the $query variable before you do mysql_query. Tell me what you see and i will help you.....

Comment: errors are vanished by this but still its not updating the record... :( i never met this tyype of sticky problem ever... :(

Comment: yup i just got tht error solved but still it wasnt working as u said now.. i  printed the $query and its updaing.. this is what i see


    UPDATE courses SET title='jnjk', description='hgszhn', 'subjects-id'='5' WHERE (id='4')

here the values right.. but i dont know where the problem is :(

Answer (score 2):

You try to access

```
$id=$_POST["id"];
$title=$_POST["title"];
$des=$_POST["description"];
$subjectid=$_POST["subjects-id"];
```

this POST variables. But when you access the script for the first time this values are not set in the POST variable.

Chck the values with [isset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php).

```
if(!isset($_POST["id"]) {
    $_POST["id"] = '';
}
```

or safe the checked value in a new variable

```
$id = isset($_POST["id"]) ? $_POST["id"] : 0;
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

@Stony's answer is good solution to check if you are sending any POST data - and if not, do not try to fetch non-existing data.

Now, if you think `$_POST["id"];` should be there, then there is something missing. Are you using GET instead of POST?

To see what data is submitted do a `print_r($_POST)`. If this is blank, do a `print_r($_REQUEST)`. If this is still blank, then no data is being submitted from the previous page.

You can also check by adding this in your URL `&id=75` (or `?id=75` if you have no other parameters in the url). This will submit data and you will see one less error.